# Typescript - Make the function return type the class that an interface implements

Tags: typescript, generics, return-type

I have the following code:

```
export enum Side {
    Left = 'left',
    Right = 'right'
}

export interface Crosser {
    side: Side 
}


export const crossersOnCorrectSide = function(crossers: Crosser[], correctSide: Side): Crosser|undefined {
    return crossers.find(crosser => { return crosser.side !== correctSide } ) 
}
```

The problem is - I don't want the return type to be `Crosser|undefined`, rather I'd like the return type to be the type of the class that is implementing `Crosser` or `undefined`.

I tried using generics and performing a type assertion:

```
export const crossersOnCorrectSide = function<T>(crossers: Crosser[], correctSide: Side): T|undefined {

    let result = crossers.find(crosser => { return crosser.side !== correctSide } ) 

    if(result !== undefined) {
        return result as T
    } 

    return result 

    //return crossers.find(crosser => { return crosser.side !== correctSide } ) 
}
```

but I got "Type Crosser cannot be converted to type T".

Is there any "correct" way of doing this, or will I be forced to use `ts-ignore`, or worse, is this bad design and should I just perform the type assertion after recieving the output of `crossersOnCorrectSide`?

Comment: Are the objects in your array all the same class or different classes implementing Crosser?

Comment: There are many different classes implement `Crosser`, but the objects in the array will always only be of one class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the caller is already using the implementing type, you can just use that type directly:

```
export const crossersOnCorrectSide = function <T extends Crosser>(crossers: T[], correctSide: Side): T | undefined {

    let result = crossers.find(crosser => { return crosser.side !== correctSide } ) 

    if(result !== undefined) {
        return result
    } 
    else return undefined 
}
```

It is common to use generics to ensure the right return type without the caller having to perform a cast. However, you'll still need to know the correct type to use for `T` when calling the function. It doesn't make any sense for your function to try and detect the actual underlying class.

Comment: Thanks! I suggested an edit that would make the function more concise when calling it, you might want to take a look.

Comment: I guess the final answer depends on whether your calling function has the array in the form of Crosser[] or already using the implementing type T[]. In the former, the function is performing the cast for the caller, in the latter the caller has already sorted it out.

Comment: Here's an example (using the edited version of your answer): `crossersOnCorrectSide(adventurers, puzzle.currentSide)`. The array `adventurers` is of type `Adventurer[]`, and the class `Adventurer` implements the `Crosser` interface.